# How to read csv file (From Microsoft Excel)

Tags: java, csv

Does anyone know how to read a csv file. Isn't it just like reading a regular .txt file or is there more to it?

Comment: Get help from a framework. There are plenty of them around. One candidate is [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: You can read it just like a regular .txt file, but it depends on what you want to do with it I guess? A scanner over the .csv would work, but it wouldn't split it on on comma's by default ;)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps ->
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

So basically there are three major options from which you can select.

1. Simple Solution:
   If you are sure the CSV files doesn’t contain “separator or double-quotes”, just use the standard split() to parse the CSV file.
2. Advance Solution:
   This solution will solve the field containing “separator or double-quotes” issue, and also support the custom separator and custom enclosed field. Review the following CSV parsing example and also the JUnit test cases to understand how it works.
3. OpenCSV Example:
   If you are not comfortable with above simple and advance solution, try using third party CSV library – OpenCSV.